# Bad data when RSA Decrypt a text file which saved as in Byte by RSA Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

Here is the method for encryption and saving to a file (both saving as String and Byte file)

```
public void Encrypt()
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider myrsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();//Encode String to Convert to Bytes

        string data = tbSerial.Text;//whatever you want to encrypt

        Byte[] newdata = encoding.GetBytes(data);//convert to Bytes

        Byte[] encrypted = myrsa.Encrypt(newdata, false);

        msg = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.Length; i++)
        {
            //textBox1.Text = "" + encrypted[i];
            string[] msg_temp = { encrypted[i].ToString() };
            foreach (string val in msg_temp)
                msg += val + " ";
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Marketing\\Serial.txt", encrypted);
}
```

This is the decryption method. Yet this caused a problem as Bad data.

```
public void Decrypt()
    {
        Byte[] bytelist;
        String mgs1 = "";

        RSACryptoServiceProvider myrsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        //this code segment Read Byte to file.
        bytelist= File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Marketing\\Serial.txt");

        Byte[] decrypted = myrsa.Decrypt(bytelist, false);//decrypt 

        string dData1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted); //Encode String to Convert to Bytes

        for (int i = 0; i < decrypted.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] mgs1_temp = { dData1[i].ToString() };
            foreach (string val in mgs1_temp)
                mgs1 += val;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Decrypted Data:  " + mgs1);
    }
```

=====================================

```
Byte[] decrypted = myrsa.Decrypt(bytelist, false);//decrypt ==> **Bad data appears here!**
```

After encrypting and saving the file, the decrypting cannot read the file. Therefore, as I thought, RSACryptoServiceProvider caused this problem. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: This is not Java. Use the appropriate language tag.

Comment: What encryption keys are you using? You don't appear to be setting the key-pair anywhere within your code, so it's probably using a newly generated key to encrypt (which since you aren't storing it is lost as soon as the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is disposed), and when decrypting you're using a completely different randomly generated key for decryption resulting in the decrypt failure you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You should either base 64 encode your ciphertext or you should rely on a binary encoded file. Currently you are storing string representation of bytes as ciphertext. In the decryption method you handle them as bytes which is not correct.

Note that using just RSA is not correct for text. RSA can only encrypt a limited amount of plaintext. Instead, hybrid encryption is normally used. A random AES key is used to encrypt the data, then this key is encrypted with the RSA public key.

Comment: Anything missing form my answer dear new user?

Answer (score -2):

A few facts about cryptography and your particular piece of code that may help you:

1. RSA is **NOT** for data encryption, it is for signatures. Being an asymmetric cipher, it was designed to serve for message signing purposes, and not encryption. While it generally works for encryption, too, it's applicability is limited. You should you a symmetric cipher like AES. Further reading: [Schneier, Bruce, Applied Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html). *Also see update below.*
2. You don't provide encryption keys *anywhere* in your code. Think *how* it could work without keys? Encryption algorithms *require*, maybe quite surprisingly, two inputs `Encrypt(data, key)` / `Decrypt(data, key)`. You've provided just the `data` portion.
3. Why, *why*, lord **WHY** (*←this emphasis is here to underline the importance of distinguishing between text and binary data*) do you store BINARY data as TEXT? Learn to store BINARY as BINARY, unless you have to store them in a generally textulal file format like XML, in which case let the XML serializer decide how best to store a chunk of BINARY data.
4. Go again through your code and think whether what you pass as input to the decryption routine actually *is* the output of the encryption. Generally, when there's a sequence of transformation, inverse transformations in (generally) reverse order must be applied to turn a *output* into a *input*. Like this:

   ```
   input -> A -> B -> C -> output
   output -> C^-1 -> B^-1 -> A^-1 -> input
   ```

   So, your encryption algorithm does:

   ```
   covert string ("ABC") to byte[] -> encrypt -> covert byte[] to string ("120 130 140")
   ```

   but your decryption algorithm is *far from* the inverse, which should be:

   ```
   convert string ("120 130 140") to byte[] -> decrypt -> covert byte[] to string ("ABC")
   ```

---

**UPDATE:** Further commentary on (1) for nitpickers, downvoters, and curious readers. When the authors of RSA first [published their paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf), they stated two important problems that had to be solved:

- establishing privacy (=encryption of messages),
- establishing signatures.

While the nitpickers and downvoters may claim I *do not* understand RSA is an ecryption algorithm *per se*, a smart reader quickly recognizes—typically from the usage of the word *cipher*—I actually *do*.

*However*, as Mr. Rivest, Mr. Shamir, and Mr. Adleman state *in their paper* in section III Privacy, i.e. in respect to encryption of messages, the cipher has certain properties that make it *less* practical for common data encryption in comparison to symmetric ciphers:

> A public-key cryptosystem can be used to “bootstrap” into a standard encryption scheme such as the NBS method. Once secure communications have been established, the rst message transmitted can be a key to use in the NBS scheme to encode all following messages. This may be desirable if encryption with our method is slower than with the standard scheme.

And yes, the vast majority of real-world RSA applications truly is for things such as key exchange and signatures. Hence for a less-experienced user of cryptography a rule of thumb should be:

- Do I need to *encrypt* data (protect privacy)? ⇒ Symmetric ciphers are the head-start.
- Do I need to create an electronic signature? ⇒ Public-key ciphers like RSA.

Plus asking yourself the question **“Is there a proven library to solve this problem?”** at the very first place. Why? There's *a lot more* needed to reach acceptable level of security than just a single “`cryptoAlg.Encrypt(data, key)`” call.

Further downvotes are welcome :-)

Comment: Whilst the writing of encrypted data to the file does appear to convert each encrypted byte to a string and write these to the output file, a closer reading reveals that this bizarre encoding is never actually used, and the encrypted data is written to and read from the file as raw binary via `File.Write/ReadAllBytes`.

Comment: @Iridium Lol, thanks for pointing that out. Originally I didn't spot this further bug. Probably the tl;dr of my answer should read "Go home and rethink your life."

Comment: Sorry, but point 1) is so [blatantly wrong](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#section-7) that I have to -1 this answer.

Comment: @owlstead Frankly, the OP barely knows what he's doing. The RFC states "operate on messages of length up to XYZ octets" - clearly demonstrating RSA encryption schemes were **not** designed to handle tons of data in generic encryption scenarios. Together, you should sense the *simplification* I've provided due to the OP's assumed level of knowledge is legitimate.